# Aptana Studio vs. Eclipse

Tags: java, php, eclipse, ide, aptana

I am a beginner. I am using Aptana Studio for PHP. Today, I also downloaded Eclipse. I notice most of the features and workings are similar. It seems one is built on the code-base of the other.

If so, what was the need for two similar Open Source IDEs on Java?

Comment: In which field are you beginner? In using Aptana or Eclipse? or, are you beginner in PHP or Java?

Comment: I am more like a beginner in Aptana.

Comment: understand. So, if you use Eclipse you can install plugin for Aptana in eclipse

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Aptana is built on Eclipse.

Eclipse is a general-purpose/Java-focused editor, whilst Aptana offers additional features which are targeted specifically at web development.

There are also other Eclipse plugins that also focus on web development, including the Web Tools Project from the Eclipse team.

Some people like Aptana, finding it a convenient mix of relevant tools. Others find Aptana too intrusive, and prefer to individually select their own plugins for JavaScript, CSS, XML, and so on.

> what was the need for two similar
>   Open Source IDEs on Java.

Variety is the spice of life. There are plenty of other IDEs aside from just these two, and the same situation applies to most software, and tools/technologies in general.

Generally, different tools don't have the same focuses, and therefore provide varying benefits for different users.

This is *especially* true in the Open Source world, where users can easily customise and re-release products to work in the way they want.

Comment: Note that Aptana's PHP support was discontinued a couple of weeks ago and they joined the efforts of Eclipse PDT (PHP Development Tools - the standards Eclipse PHP plugin). So, when it comes to plain PHP editing, Aptana offers the same functionality.

Comment: Aptana is going to support PHP again in version 3

Comment: And Eclipse has never just been a editor, for Java or otherwise.  It's a full application platform that initially came out packaged with Java and plug-in development tools on top of it.

Comment: I downloaded elipse a couple of months ago. But, couldnot use it bcz it was cpu hungry, atleat on my machine. Today I downloaded aptana 3 and to me suprise it is working smoothly.

Answer (score 17):

You might wonder why the developers of Aptana built a "new" IDE based on Eclipse rather than simply working on Eclipse plugins.

The reason for this is that there used to be a paid-for Pro version of Aptana. This no longer exists however; you can get all the Aptana features now in the free Community Edition.

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for an free / open source IDE for PHP development i suggest Eclipse. If you can give some money to some company i suggest you give a try PHP Designer. PHP Designer supports as you guess PHP and debugging, also javascript framework like jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Aptana Studio 3 myself and I have to say that I like it so far. Which is odd because after using the IDEs I have used in the past I always ended up back with a text editor to write my code in.

I was curious about Eclipse as well and that is why I ended up at your question. I watched the [Eclipse demo](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=409) at the Eclipse site and I think I'll be sticking with Aptana. Just because it does appear to look and function very similar and I have decided that I do like Aptana. I was just searching to see if that was a certain feature or improvement Eclipse could offer.