# [Aptana/Eclipse]: Which one is better?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I want to know which one is stable, fast and easy to use?

Comment: I'd wager 2 cahoolis: it's for php.

Comment: I am using Aptana for PHP and want to use it for Ruby also.

Comment: I don't get it - given your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607226/aptana-studio-vs-eclipse - how does thies one differ? Aptana-Eclipse Smackdown 2.0

Comment: @martin: Actually I wanted to ask some more questions in my previous link but I decided to post a new to get fresh replies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aptana is built on eclipse.

Aptana can also be installed as an eclipse plugin if you already have a well set-up eclipse environment.

If you mean "which is better [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), or aptana?" I'd have to go with Aptana. If only because it also does lots of other things well. The PHP support isn't significantly different from PDT to make it worth the added weight Aptana brings with it. However, you're probably also looking for a good css editor, Javascript editor, etc, and Aptana does those well.

Comment: Aptana recently dropped their PHP support and joined PDT. Their site points to PDT installation. You can read more in the nWire blog: http://bit.ly/3tc6WQ

Answer (score 7):

I installed the **Aptana Studio Eclipse plugin** this year when I was playing with Rails for fun. Eclipse was never the same again. Suddenly it took two or three times as long to load any Java or Haskell project, Eclipse started crashing intermittently and it completely messed up my layout. It wouldn't let me uninstall it and "manually" uninstalling it seemed to make it worse!

Rails was fun to play with but I had to learn to live with the Aptana plugin. I eventually got rid of it by totally deleting Eclipse and starting over. It wouldn't have been so bad if it didn't seem to take over Eclipse in a Cthulu-like way. I really liked the integration with Rails which was done well, and it seemed to be have a lot of features that would be useful on larger systems.

Answer (score 3):

I use Eclipse for all my work, have done for years. Perfectly happy with it.

Must admit I've not done any detailed comparisons with other IDEs. I fear that getting objective comparisons between IDEs may be quite tricky. I think that the vi v emacs wars still rumble on on some areas.

Answer (score 3):

Another Happy [**Eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/) User here.

- My personal opinion. I use it for mainly Java and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you write PHP codes in Aptana i do not suggest it. Because Aptana 2.0 does not provide PHP plug in. It installs Eclipse as a plug in. So install Eclipse (actually PDT) and use it for PHP development will be better choice.